# Docker - can not get through port in container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I can not get through port in container . I used this address: 0.0.0.0.:5000 and see: http://joxi.ru/Vm6oegWtxoQVK2. I'm running through: 'docker-compose up -d'. When enter this command 'docker ps' I see it:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4fea50856eef        docker_web          "python manage.py ru…"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   docker_web_1
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /django.testsite/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Docerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip install django==1.9.12
RUN pip install requests

ADD . /.
WORKDIR /django.testsite

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "5000"]
```

How solve?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a real IP. Use http://localhost:5000

Comment: Not working: http://joxi.ru/YmEMe47hZQadlm and I'm change port to 8000

Comment: 5000 is fine... You do need CMD to be `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`, though

Comment: Not working, please see: https://github.com/seferaua/testsite. I can not understand what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you don't expose the port in Dockerfile. Add

`EXPOSE 8000` in Dockerfile before CMD

For Example:

```
FROM python:3

RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip install django==1.9.12
RUN pip install requests

ADD . /.
WORKDIR /django.testsite
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

For more info https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: I could do a get to your web app's root without any connection refused errors. Only thing is you haven't got your homepage configured correctly. Have you rebuilt the image and run a new container using that image?

Comment: Yes, I re-compose image with add the EXPOSE, but when visit to 0.0.0.0:8000 shows this: joxi.ru/E2pq5Y8cBgJdQA 
P.S. I update code and push to github and used 'docker-compose up -d'

Comment: works fine for me, what's your `docker-compose ps` returns?

Comment: What's your host IP address? can you try `<hostip>:8000`?

Comment: My ip is end on 57 and added number port: http://joxi.ru/zANWZKlSlRgJkr

Comment: Your docker image works fine for me, don't know why it's not working, could be a networking issue.

Comment: Your clone of my site? Do you see homepage and weather for the three city ?